# Sunspot / SOLR not indexing STI models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, solr, sunspot-rails

I have a couple of models in a Rails (2.3.11) application that are built using STI, and arranged as such:

`Gallery::Base < ActiveRecord::Base` (indexed for SOLR)

`Gallery::Local < Gallery::Base`     (indexed for SOLR)

`Gallery::Remote < Gallery::Base`    (not indexed)

I am finding disparate results regarding the indexing of these models. In my current development database I have 77 `Gallery::Local` objects and no `Gallery::Remote` objects (which also means there are 77 `Gallery::Base` objects in the db)

The problem is that either `Sunspot.search(Gallery::Base)` as well as `Sunspot.search(Gallery::Local)` returns a single hit.

Now for the stranger part: on a colleague's computer using the production database (with hundreds of `Gallery::Local` objects), no hit whatsoever is returned from either `Sunspot.search(Gallery::Base)` or `Sunspot.search(Gallery::Local)`!

On a side note, I have tried having the index on both `Gallery::Base` and `Gallery::Local`, and in each one separately and reindexing, with the same results. I also have a number of other indexed models for which the full text search works as intended.

Anyone have any idea as what's causing this?

Comment: Are you using thinkingsphinx or something like this? If not, can you show us `search` method?

Comment: Actually I just found out what the problem was. The rake task `sunspot:reindex` only reindexes models directly under `app/models`. As our `Gallery` models are namespaced (inside `app/models/gallery`), they were simply ignored. Calling `Gallery::Base.reindex` solved the problem :/

Comment: Also, forgot to tell we're using Sunspot / SOLR instead of ThinkingSphinx / Sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found out what the problem was. If anyone's interested, the `sunspot:reindex` task does not contemplate namespaced and 'moduled' models.

Check out this [pull request](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/36) on github for a fix (go to the Diff section).

Comment: @Meliborn I have edited the answer, the pull request link is now working (the url was from an old github username)